# Use Current User's Credentials for SharePoint Online C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, user, spcontext, credentials

I am currently using my account's credentials to run some custom code in my SharePoint Online provider-hosted Add-in.

I am passing the credentials this way:

```
SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in "my password here".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("my login here", passWord);
```

This works just fine, but is there a way I could use current user's credentials instead, without hard-coding login and password?

```
clientContext.Credentials = ???
```

Thanks!

**Update:**

I've tried

```
clientContext.Credentials = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.Context.Credentials;
```

But I get "error: (403) Forbidden" this way...

Comment: Check this MSDN link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh124553%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: @Hardik , this way I get "error: (401) Unauthorized"

Comment: You can get your credentials from web.config so you do not need to hard-code in code behind.

Comment: @Hardik , I've tried it but then I get  "error: (403) Forbidden"

Comment: If you're using a provider-hosted add-in, why not use the `SharePointContextProvider` and `TokenHelper` classes?

Comment: I haven't done this myself and I can't find link to a good resource but... I'm pretty sure you can cache access and refresh tokens for users of your App. Then you can use those cached tokens to create a ClientContext impersonating a specific user. The only drawback of this technique is that you can only impersonate users who have used the App previously. I hope this helps.

Comment: @RobWindsor , That's the problem, I can't find any good resources about this... All the examples on MSDN don't use credentials and all the other topics use hard-coded credentials... I still think there should be an easy way to get current SP user's credentials as it is on-prem...

Comment: You can get the current user's credentials by using the two classes that Microsoft includes in the Provider-Hosted add-in template...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am facing the same needs..

Answer (score 3):

I've read a few articles about the topic linked here and a bit curious no one yet has mentioned yet the Windows Credentials Manager.

This is my code to read/write from SharePoint from an application installed as Windows Service:

```
        NetworkCredential networkCredentials = WebCredentialMgr.GetCredential(sharePointUser);
        T result = default(T);
        using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(sharePointUri))
        {
             if (networkCredentials != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(networkCredentials.UserName))
            {   // works only when stored in the 'Web Credentials' not as Windows Credentials :(
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(networkCredentials.UserName, networkCredentials.SecurePassword);
            }
            else
            {   // default code from MSDN, does not work for SharePoint Online
                clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                clientContext.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            }
            result = action(clientContext);
        }
```

where

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using Windows.Security.Credentials;

public static class WebCredentialMgr
{
    public static NetworkCredential GetCredential(string userName)
    {
        PasswordCredential credential = GetCredentialFromLocker(userName);
        if (credential == null)
            return null;

        credential.RetrievePassword();

        var networkCred = new NetworkCredential(credential.UserName, credential.Password);
        return networkCred;
    }

    private static PasswordCredential GetCredentialFromLocker(string userName)
    {
        PasswordCredential credential = null;
        IReadOnlyList<PasswordCredential> credentialList = null;

        var vault = new PasswordVault();
        try
        {
            credentialList = vault.FindAllByUserName(userName);
        }
        catch
        {
             // log error  
        }
        if (credentialList == null)
            credentialList = vault.RetrieveAll();

        if (credentialList != null && credentialList.Count > 0)
        {
            if (credentialList.Count == 1)
            {
                credential = credentialList[0];
            }
            else
            {
                // manage issue when multiple user names
            }
        }
        return credential;
    }
}
```

Log once in your SharePoint site with the wished credentials, and let Internet Explorer remember your password: it will be saved into Windows Web Credentials.
And using the code above, you can simply read it from your program.

Comment: This almost worked for me... But I eventually got `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException: 'The partner returned a bad sign-in name or password error. For more information, see Federation Error-handling Scenarios.'` I suppose this doesn't work in 2-factor auth scenarios.

Comment: not able to find Windows.Security.Credentials, any help?

Answer (score 1):

The only tricky part for accessing SharePoint Online from the Client Object Model will be the authentication. There is no direct method of authenticating with SharePoint Online from the CSOM so Microsoft has released a work around.

You can find the details and code here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/03/authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx

So what it basically does is:

1. Opens up a browser Instance
2. Authenticates with the browser
3. Grabs the authentication cookie and passes it to the Client Object Model.

The rest of the tasks should be quite straight forward. You can find many code samples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537013.aspx

UPDATE: You this technique to allow the authentication to happen without a human running the console app: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx

Comment: As you can see in my question, I have the working code. I don't want to hard-code credentials anywhere. I need to use current user's credentials as the add-in will be used by other people as well.

Comment: Please check this http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/01/authenticating-net-client-object-model.html?showComment=1383574323741#c6138358494645297363

Comment: yes, I use this code at the moment, but I don't want ANY hard-coded credentials in my code

Comment: Please find my updated answer.

Comment: Hello Gintas, Is that working for you?

Comment: i have seen your comment & there you have mentioned that you are working on SharePoint on-premises version. **Is that true?** as i have posted the answer for SharePoint Online not for SharePoint on-premises.

Comment: ,I'm developing on SharePoint Online, I just said in the comment that it's easy on-prem, but complex Online...

Comment: Ok, i misunderstood the entire comment.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution from Microsoft for a service application is however via a dedicated token for that app via a x509 certificate:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/building-service-apps-in-office-365