# Authentication to Sharepoint Online stopped working

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, credentials

I have a C# app using CSOM (latest version v16.1.19223.1200), and it worked fine until about mid-Aug-2019. I verified that the actual password is still valid.

Code:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(SharepointFolder))
{
    // Can't use current user, tried workaround linked from https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176375/use-current-users-credentials-for-sharepoint-online-c

    var creds = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "creds.txt"));
    string userUpn = creds[0];
    // var spassword = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userUpn, creds[1]).SecurePassword; // tried this as well
    var spassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in creds[1]) { spassword.AppendChar(c); }
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userUpn, spassword);

    Utils.Log.Info($"Getting page list from {context.Url}");

    var pagesList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
    context.Load(pagesList);
    context.ExecuteQuery();  ///// throws: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException  HResult=0x80048821  Message=The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.

    // ...
}
```

I've traced this with Fiddler, and basically got:

```
#   Result  Protocol Host                       URL
2   401     HTTPS   microsoft.sharepoint.com    /   <<<<<<<<<< Why not the path I provided in SharepointFolder?
3   502     HTTP    msoid.microsoft.com         /FPUrl.xml  
5   200     HTTPS   login.microsoftonline.com   /GetUserRealm.srf
7   200     HTTPS   msft.sts.microsoft.com      /adfs/services/trust/2005/usernamemixed
8   200     HTTPS   login.microsoftonline.com   /rst2.srf
```

Tracing Fiddler with browser access to the same address shows me the first access to `SharepointFolder`, getting 302-redirected to authentication and working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if Multi-Factor authentication(MFA) is enabled.

If the MFA is enabled, we have to use PnP Core library, if it is not installed on your environment then please install it using NuGet manager.

```
Install-Package SharePointPnPCoreOnline -Version 3.13.1909
```

Code:

```
string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";  
AuthenticationManager authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();  
ClientContext context = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteUrl);
```

References:

[Office 365 : Connecting to SharePoint online site using CSOM when Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) is enabled for the user](https://knowledge-junction.com/2017/12/24/office-365-connecting-to-sharepoint-online-site-using-csom-when-multi-factor-authentication-mfa-is-enabled-for-the-user/)

[Authenticate SharePoint Using PnP Authentication Manager](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authenticate-sharepoint-using-pnp-authentication-manager/)

Comment: Works great, and it uses currently logged-on user as well - no more clunky password!

Comment: As SharePointPnPCoreOnline is deprecated now, how can we authenticate using username,password with MFA enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

For the record (since I'm still battling this kind of thing in .Net Framework in 2023), you can get some tracing out of the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client CSOM assembly by adding something like the following into the configuration element of your web.config / app.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true">
  <listeners>
    <add name="textWriterTraceListener" />
  </listeners>
</trace>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="textWriterTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="DateTime,ThreadId" initializeData="TraceCSOMAuth.log" />
</sharedListeners>
<sources>
  <source name="CSOMAuth" switchValue="Verbose">
    <listeners>
      <add name="textWriterTraceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

You might then see something that will give you clues as to the issue, like:

> CSOMAuth Information: 4839637 : Response.StatusCode=Unauthorized,
> Headers=X-NetworkStatistics=0,8409600,0,92,5509151,0,4392247,
> X-SharePointHealthScore=2, X-MSDAVEXT_Error=917656;
> Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically., SPRe...

Comment: Okay, so my issue here in November 2023 is a bit of a weird one.  The above line is a red herring - the issue is further up in the log where a request is made to msoid.co.uk.  I guess this used to fail in some way but has now started succeeding and returning an empty document, which is causing the authentication issue.  I've fixed it by adding an msoid.co.uk entry to my hosts file to repoint it to a server that times out.  Some other people have also found the issue and are using 127.0.0.1 to cause more rapid failures.  E.g. See...

Comment: https://moresharepoints.blogspot.com/2019/05/root-element-missing-when-connecting-to.html
and
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/client-context-from-sharepoint-online-running-slow-in-the-last/m-p/623216